# como puedo contar los elementos display none de un div que dentro tiene otro div y dentro hay una article con display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de contar los elementos dentro de un div y dentro de ese hay un article y algunos de esos article tengo un display none, y  siempre que tiene display none tiene la clase tg-item-hidden, pero no puedo hacerlo, me dice que hay cero elementos

les dejo un ejemplo de como trate de hacerlo

```
var numElem = $('article.tg-item-hidden').size

alert(numElem);
```

dejo mi html donde tengo problemas

```
<div id="grid-profesional">
<!-- The Grid Plugin Version 2.6.0 --><!-- The Grid Wrapper Start -->
<div class="tg-grid-wrapper tg-txt full-height tg-grid-loaded" id="grid-6966" data-version="2.6.0"><!-- The Grid Styles -->
  <div class="tg-grid-holder tg-layout-grid" style="left: -3px; width: 1425px; position: relative; height: 195px;">
    <!-- The Grid item #1 -->
    <article class="tg-item tg-post-1873 tg-profesional f111 f12 f8 f7 f110 f22 f45 f70 f40 tg-item-hidden" data-row="1" data-col="1" style="width: 195px; height: 195px; position: absolute; display: none;">
      <div class="tg-item-inner">
        <div class="tg-item-media-holder tg-light">
          <div class="tg-item-media-inner">
            <div class="tg-item-image" style="background-image: url(http://embajadorestec.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/a879cc_1081cca149a74525ad13b7cf759e331b~mv2_d_1538_1923_s_2-320x320.jpg)"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="tg-item-media-content ">
            <div class="tg-item-overlay"></div>
            <div class="tg-top-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-1"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/juanpablosanchez/">NEGOCIOS</a></span><h2 class="tg-item-title tg-element-2"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/juanpablosanchez/">Juan Pablo Sánchez</a></h2></div><div class="tg-bottom-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-5"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/juanpablosanchez/">Primer Semestre</a></span><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/juanpablosanchez/">Hidalgo</a></span></div></div></div></div></article>
    <!-- The Grid item #2 -->
    <article class="tg-item tg-post-4704 tg-profesional f112 f12 f8 f7 f46 f110 f22 f47 f45 f70 f40" data-row="1" data-col="1" style="width: 195px; height: 195px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transition-property: opacity, transform; transition-duration: 2060ms;"><div class="tg-item-inner"><div class="tg-item-media-holder tg-light"><div class="tg-item-media-inner"><div class="tg-item-image" style="background-image: url(http://embajadorestec.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Tiffany_Fondo_grid-320x320.jpg)"></div></div><div class="tg-item-media-content "><div class="tg-item-overlay"></div><div class="tg-top-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-1"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/tiffany/">LAEt</a></span><h2 class="tg-item-title tg-element-2"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/tiffany/">Tiffany Thalia Corona</a></h2></div><div class="tg-bottom-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-5"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/tiffany/">Sexto Semestre</a></span><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/tiffany/">Hidalgo</a></span></div></div></div></div></article>
          <!-- The Grid item #3 --><article class="tg-item tg-post-4135 tg-profesional f112 f12 f107 f8 f7 f46 f110 f22 f70 f40 f50" data-row="1" data-col="1" style="width: 195px; height: 195px; position: absolute; left: 205px; top: 0px; transition-property: opacity, transform; transition-duration: 2060ms;"><div class="tg-item-inner"><div class="tg-item-media-holder tg-light"><div class="tg-item-media-inner"><div class="tg-item-image" style="background-image: url(http://embajadorestec.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Ixchel_Fondo_grid-320x320.jpg)"></div></div><div class="tg-item-media-content "><div class="tg-item-overlay"></div><div class="tg-top-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-1"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/ixchel/">LDP</a></span><h2 class="tg-item-title tg-element-2"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/ixchel/">Ixchel Alondra León</a></h2></div><div class="tg-bottom-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-5"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/ixchel/">Segundo Semestre</a></span><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/ixchel/">Hidalgo</a></span></div></div></div></div></article>
          <!-- The Grid item #4 --><article class="tg-item tg-post-4697 tg-profesional f112 f12 f8 f7 f46 f110 f22 f43 f70 f40 f48" data-row="1" data-col="1" style="width: 195px; height: 195px; position: absolute; left: 410px; top: 0px; transition-property: opacity, transform; transition-duration: 2060ms;"><div class="tg-item-inner"><div class="tg-item-media-holder tg-light"><div class="tg-item-media-inner"><div class="tg-item-image" style="background-image: url(http://embajadorestec.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Kevin_Fondo_grid-320x320.jpg)"></div></div><div class="tg-item-media-content "><div class="tg-item-overlay"></div><div class="tg-top-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-1"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/kevinbarrera/">ITIt</a></span><h2 class="tg-item-title tg-element-2"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/kevinbarrera/">Kevin Barrera</a></h2></div><div class="tg-bottom-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-5"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/kevinbarrera/">Sexto Semestre</a></span><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/kevinbarrera/">Hidalgo</a></span></div></div></div></div></article>
          <!-- The Grid item #5 --><article class="tg-item tg-post-1871 tg-profesional f111 f12 f8 f7 f110 f22 f45 f70 tg-item-hidden" data-row="1" data-col="1" style="width: 195px; height: 195px; position: absolute; display: none;"><div class="tg-item-inner"><div class="tg-item-media-holder tg-light"><div class="tg-item-media-inner"><div class="tg-item-image" style="background-image: url(http://embajadorestec.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/a879cc_45ac8bd3c7a847fc876717d363725a9f~mv2_d_1517_1896_s_2-320x320.jpg)"></div></div><div class="tg-item-media-content "><div class="tg-item-overlay"></div><div class="tg-top-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-1"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/danielortega/">NEGOCIOS</a></span><h2 class="tg-item-title tg-element-2"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/danielortega/">Daniel Ortega</a></h2></div><div class="tg-bottom-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-5"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/danielortega/">Primer Semestre</a></span><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/danielortega/">Hidalgo</a></span></div></div></div></div></article></div></div><!-- The Grid Wrapper End --> 
</div>
```

esta es la clase que tiene el article que tengo que contar: `tg-item tg-post-1873 tg-profesional f111 f12 f8 f7 f110 f22 f45 f70 f40 tg-item-hidden`

Comment: Veo que las dos respuestas que han publicado son correctas y funcionan para el HTML propuesto, ¿acaso hay alguna condición como ajax que actualice el DOM?

Comment: solo esta filtrado, muestra ciertos elementos dependiendo de la pagina en la que estes, como te digo , si c ambio cualquier clase que tenga ese article si me hace la contabilización excepto solo cuando uso la de hidden,  ¿te paso la pagina del plugin o donde yo lo estoy utilizando?

Comment: Ya encontré cual es el plugin, y en efecto lo que hace es ocultar los elementos de la grilla por ajax, agregando la clase respectiva `tg-item-hidden`.

Comment: si, y necesito esa clase para poder saber cuantos elementos hay visibles y cuales no para poder centrar el grid en medio, ya que dependiendo del numero de elementos es como se va a centrar.

Comment: ¿hay algún evento que active dicho conteo?

Comment: queria que hiciera eso al entrar a la pagina

Comment: hay alguna forma de poder utilizar esa clase aunque fuera agregada por ajax?

Comment: Vi que formulaste otra pregunta, por lo cual te sugiero que aceptes una de las respuestas de esta, pues ambas cumplen con el requisito solicitado.

Comment: ok, y para mi otra duda tengo que hacer formular otra publicacion?

Comment: Sí, es mejor, puesto que en esta no se conocía de antemano que había ajax involucrado y se presta para confusiones.

Comment: muchas gracias, ya acepte una respuesta, gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para contar la cantidad de elementos `article` que contienen la clase `tg-item-hidden` utiliza el atributo length de los arreglos

```
var numElem =$('article.tg-item-hidden').length;
alert(numElem);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, pero tambien ya habia intentado ese metodo, pero me sigue saliendo en el alert 0 a pesar de que si estan ahi

Comment: Los article se agregan por medio de ajax? Puedes colocar ejemplos del html de esos articles

Comment: es un plug-in de wordpress de que llama un grid , de hecho lo extraño es que si utilizo alguna otra clase que tiene ese article si funciona excepto solo cuando quiero buscarlo por esa clase, y si necesito usar esa clase porque es la que me dice si esta oculta o no, o contarlo por medio de los display:none, pero tampoco me ha funcionado. te pongo un ejemplo , de como esta estructurado pero si sale super mal acomodado, ahi una disculpa

Comment: listo, ahi esta mi html

Comment: Prueba con `$('#grid-profesional article.tg-item-hidden').length;`

Comment: Debe haber ajax o algo porque esta respuesta y la otra funcionan correctamente con el HTML planteado.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con js puro a ver, poniendo:

```
var numElem = document.getElementsByClassName("tg-item-hidden").length;
```

Comment: muchas gracias, lamentablemente me sale que son 0 elementos aun :(

Comment: no aun no se puede :(

Comment: Entonces debe ser de otra cosa, porque eso no deberia fallar

Comment: creo que es porque se agrega esa clase por medio de ajax ¿sabes como puedo hacer uso de esa clase aunque fue agregada por ajax?

Comment: Pon el resto del codigo a ver

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar con este script:

```
<script>
 $( window ).load(function() {
        var Elementosprofe =$('#grid-profesional article').length;
        var ElementosOcultosprofe =$('#grid-profesional article.tg-item-hidden').length;
        var totalprofe = Elementosprofe-ElementosOcultosprofe;
        if(totalprofe == 1 )
        {
           $("#grid-profesional").addClass("large-offset-5");
        }
        if(totalprofe == 2 )
        {
           $("#grid-profesional").addClass("large-offset-4");
        }
         if(totalprofe == 3 )
        {
           $("#grid-profesional").addClass("large-offset-3");
        }
         if(totalprofe == 4 )
        {
           $("#grid-profesional").addClass("large-offset-2");
        }
         if(totalprofe == 5 )
        {
           $("#grid-profesional").addClass("large-offset-1");
        }
         if(totalprofe == 6 )
        {
           $("#grid-profesional").addClass("large-offset-1");
        }
         var Elementosprepa =$('#grid-preparatoria article').length;
        var ElementosOcultosprepa =$('#grid-preparatoria article.tg-item-hidden').length;
        var totalprepa = Elementosprepa-ElementosOcultosprepa;
        if(totalprepa == 1 )
        {
           $("#grid-preparatoria").addClass("large-offset-5");
        }
         if(totalprepa == 2 )
        {
           $("#grid-preparatoria").addClass("large-offset-4");
        }
         if(totalprepa == 3 )
        {
           $("#grid-preparatoria").addClass("large-offset-3");
        }
          if(totalprepa == 4 )
        {
           $("#grid-preparatoria").addClass("large-offset-2");
        }
          if(totalprepa == 5 )
        {
           $("#grid-preparatoria").addClass("large-offset-1");
        }
          if(totalprepa == 6 )
        {
           $("#grid-preparatoria").addClass("large-offset-1");
        }

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Podrias explicar más como llegaste a esta solución para que sea aceptada tu respuesta